# Create custom filter for [tag1] and ([tag2] or [tag3])

Tags: support, custom-filters

Is it possible to create a custom filter that searches like this? My example would be to have a custom filter `[python] and ([unit-testing] or [integration-testing])`. There are a few questions already on meta about similar things but most of them are so old that the answers there don't apply anymore.

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq++%5Bunit-testing%5D+or+%5Bintegration-testing%5D&mixed=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following combination will work:

[[python] and [unit-testing] or [python] and [integration-testing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20and%20unit-testing%20or%20python%20and%20integration-testing?sort=Newest&edited=true)

i.e., `[tag1] and [tag2] or [tag1] and [tag3]`

> [image]